# Open files in windows server as an admin

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server

Currently, when I open any file in notepad in windows server, and edit, it won't allow me to edit. I don't want to right click on notepad first, and then choose run as administrator, then navigate to the file location and open it. I want to always open any file by double click and it would open as an admin. How do I do that?

I am using windows server 2012.

Comment: Log in with administrative credentials.

Comment: I am logged in with an admin. I am in the local administrators gorup

Comment: no windows admin knows about this?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If opening notepad using right-click run as administrator allows you to edit then it's User Account Control rather than file system permissions that is causing the behaviour.

You can deactivate UAC completely, see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx

Before doing so you should understand why UAC is on by default and therefore what the downsides could be https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574089(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Another admin on the server doesn't have this problem, is this setting shared between users or is it per user?

Comment: No, but there is a difference in UAC with being an admin through local group permissions and inheriting local admin rights via domain group membership such as domain admins.